# Bad json format when loading data from file

Tags: python, json, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I try to create an azure ad b2c user flow using [microsoft graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identitycontainer-post-b2cuserflows?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) :

**user_flow.json**

```json
{
    "id": "Customer",
    "userFlowType": "signUpOrSignIn",
    "userFlowTypeVersion": 3
}
```

**main.py**

```py
    def create_user_flow(jsonConfigFile, msgraph_token):
        url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows/"
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + msgraph_token
        }     
        with open(jsonConfigFile) as data :
            payload = (json.load(data))
            data.close()
        
        r = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        return r.json()

print(create_user_flow("user_flow.json",get_graph_token())
```

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "BadRequest",
> "message": **"Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format."**,
> "innerError": {
> "date": "2022-04-13T13:09:00",
> "request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
> "client-request-id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
> }
> } }

But if I hardcode the `json` as follow, it works :

```py
    def create_user_flow(jsonConfigFile, msgraph_token):
        url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows/"
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + msgraph_token
        }     
        payload = json.dumps({
            "id": "Customer",
            "userFlowType": "signUpOrSignIn",
            "userFlowTypeVersion": 3
        })
        
        r = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        return r.json()

print(create_user_flow("user_flow.json",get_graph_token())
```

Could someone explain me what I am doing wrong while loading my json from a file ?

Comment: When POSTing JSON use json=payload rather than data=payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.load` creates a new dictionary with the key-value pairs of the JSON string and it returns this new dictionary.

You can read the data as a string and send it in the request

```
def create_user_flow(jsonConfigFile, msgraph_token):
        url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows/"
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + msgraph_token
        }     
        with open(jsonConfigFile) as data :
            payload = data.read()
            data.close()
        
        r = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
        return r.json()

print(create_user_flow("user_flow.json",get_graph_token())
```

or call json.dumps for load JSON dictionary.

```
def create_user_flow(jsonConfigFile, msgraph_token):
        url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows/"
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + msgraph_token
        }     
        with open(jsonConfigFile) as data :
        payload = (json.load(data))
        data.close()
        
        r = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
        return r.json()

print(create_user_flow("user_flow.json",get_graph_token())
```